# Twitter Widget doesn't work in IE8 when inside an iFrame

Tags: javascript, twitter, widget

I'm using a Twitter widget and it works fine in IE8, until I put it inside an iFrame. The twitter widgets Javascript file is being loaded from within the iFrame, and as I said it works perfectly on it's own. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of testing it seems that the order in which the JavaScript is loaded was causing the problem. I had a lot of JavaScript on the page, and after moving the Twitter script tag above all other javascript or css tags in the head of my document it worked!